# Add a HtmlGenericControl to master page from server code

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a website which allows users to log in. After logging in successfully, user's name should be displayed across each page, for example, at the top right corner. I have a ContentPlaceHolder on Master Page. An h3 tag would then be created and added into this ContentPlaceHolder.

Master Page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="UserNamePlaceHolder">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Login Page:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master" %>
```

Login Class:

```
protected void Login_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder userNamePlaceHolder = 
        (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("UserNamePlaceHolder");
    var h3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
    h3.InnerHtml = login.UserName;
    userNamePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(h3);
}
```

I did debugging step by step. Nothing went wrong: no null or empty value, each variable was created. However, the user name was not displayed at all. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and better approach would be to create a public property on the Master page:

```
public string UserName
{
  get
  {
    return Literal1.Text;
  }
  set
  {
    Literal1.Text = value;
  }
}
```

That's it place the literal with ID `Literal1` anywhere you want on the master page:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" />
```

You are already adding Master directive for strongly typing Master class, so now your login class would look like this:

```
protected void Login_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.UserName = login.UserName;
    userNamePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(h3);
}
```

Hope this helps.